# how can I skip a string if it contains some word by using regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to skip the string if it contains 'have' after Vehicles word
str 1 = "3 Vehicles have already been added",
str 2 = "13 Vehicles"
Regex I m using = `([0-9]+)[\s]*Vehicles[\s]*[^have]`

output needed is "13 Vehicles"(only) but "3 Vehicles" is also matches..that is not right

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide a compilable code, please.

Comment: Do you also want to match "vehicles" (lower-case v)?

Comment: that I am using in my regex "(?i)" in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert that  `have` is not directly at the right.

The negated character class `[^have]` matches a single char which is not any of the listed chars.

```
[0-9]+\h+Vehicles(?!\h+have\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DrZVxa/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "[0-9]+\\h+Vehicles(?!\\h+have\\b)";
```